# Can't install yiidebugtb extension in Yii application

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I have downloaded the yiidebugtb extension and put it in the protected/extensions directory, so the path to the `XWebDebugRouter.php` file is `protected/extensions/yiidebugtb/XWebDebugRouter.php`. Then I updated the `main.php` config file so that I added this line `'application.extensions.yiidebugtb.*',` in the 'import' section, so this extension is loaded automatically.

However, when I try to access the main page of my application I am getting this error

`include(XWebDebugRouter.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

in YiiBase.php(421). Anyone could help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The directory

`protected/extensions/yiidebugtb`

had incorrect access rights. It only had `rwx------`, after chmod to `rwxr-xr-x` it is alright.